# Указатель на абстрактный класс

Tags: c++, ооп

Ситуация: есть абстрактный класс (названия от балды) Father, наследуемый от него класс Sister и просто класс Child. В Child есть Father* mom, в который конструктор записывает адрес Sister. В Father есть чисто виртуальный метод getName(), который переопределен в Sister. Вопрос: как я из Child могу обратиться к методу getName() класса Sister, скажем из какого-то метода foo()?

```
void foo()
{
   mom->getName(); //не сработает, и если указать Mom::, даже если есть доступ
}
```

Если так нельзя, то как можно? И какие существуют альтернативы? Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да как обычно... Как видите, `mom->getName();` отлично работает.

```
class Father
{
public:
    virtual void getName() = 0
    {
        cout << "Father\n";
    }
};

class Sister: public Father
{
public:
    void getName() override
    {
        cout << "Sister\n";
    }
};


class Child
{
public:
    Child():mom(new Sister){}
    ~Child(){ delete mom;}

    void foo()
    {
        mom->getName();
    }
private:
    Father * mom;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Child c;
    c.foo();
}
```

Деструкторы для краткости не определял; по-хорошему, нужны виртуальные деструкторы `Father` и `Sister`.

Comment: Прикол в том, что такая модель у меня не работает, в Qt :(, был бы очень признателен, если бы вы глянули, уже замучился https://github.com/Xambey/QSnake , иерархия та же, есть SnakeBase = Farher, Snake = Sister, ItemSnake = Child

Comment: @Xambey Qt не занимаюсь, на машине нет, так что компилировать и проверять негде. Если есть минимальный пример без использования Qt...

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/qt/thread1779395.html#post9363603 вот описание, в Qt для этого разбираться не нужно, где я накосячил с точки зрения ООП?

Comment: @Xambey ошибки компилятора покажите.

Comment: 'ItemSnake' does not name a type
     virtual ItemSnake* getPrevItem(ItemSnake* item) = 0;
и все в таком роде, больше всего у меня мысли на узел включений

Comment: т.е показывает, что не может вызвать getPrevItem(...) , т.к он не определен, вообщем смотрит на "реализацию которой нет "в абк вместо Snake

Comment: @Xambey а вы уверены что это метод `virtual`? Если нет, то приводите напрямую...

Comment: уверн, чисто виртуальный он

Comment: @Xambey так это он на тип возвращаемого значения ругается. Так напишите ему до начала декларации class, в котором вы делаете виртуальный метод: class ItemSnake;

Comment: делал, не робит, вообщем в крайнем случае поменяю модель, сделаю без абк

Comment: @Xambey у вас там просто детские помарки. Принимайте пулл-реквест.

Comment: Вы не сделали запрос

Comment: @gbg https://github.com/Xambey/QSnake/invitations

Comment: @gbg спасибо!!!

Comment: @Xambey поройтесь в diff, посмотрите, что я наисправлял.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42371/discussion-between-gbg-and-xambey).

Answer (score 1):

## Привести типы:

```
auto Sist=dynamic_cast<Child*>(mom);
if(Sist)
{
    Sist->getName();
}
```

Проверка `if(Sist)` нужна для того, что если `mom` не типа `Child` (а это можно узнать только в рантайме), не сотворить UB.

## Виртуальный метод у `Father`:

```
class Father
{
    public: 
       virtual string getName() const=0;
}


class Child: public Father
{
    const string name;
    public: 
       virtual string getName() const
       {  
           return name;
       }
}
```

Comment: оО а по другому никак?Меня просто удивило: по идее с точки зрения компилятора он видет: так что тут у нас, есть один метод с таким именем в абк, есть в производном, неужели ему нельзя явно указать метод какого класса нужно использовать?

Comment: Если судить вашему коду, то учитывать, что вызываю я getName из Sister

Comment: А если потом будет определен еще один наследник? и использован в качестве `mom`? Ощущение, что тут решение в духе "зачем просто, если можно сложно". Все равно ведь `mom = new Father` невозможно.

Comment: @Harry либо делаем гомологию классов, как сделал автор (не ясно, почему она у него не работает), либо используем RTII. RTII хорош тем, что позволяет вызывать разные методы в зависимости от типа наследника.